# Getting the right index value for an array

Tags: java, sorting, indexing

I have a problem I can't quite solve. 
I am trying to create a method in which I want to return an int-array with indexes in sorted order for the 3 first numbers in a table "a".
For instance if I have the a containing {8,9,4}, I would like to return {2,0,1}.
This because 2 is the index of the smallest number, 0 is the index for the 2. smallest number, and 1 is the index for the largest of the three.
Another example: a={2,6,3}, then the return value would be {0,2,1}.

I have also created a method but I just can't get it to work.

Also: Indeks = index

```
public static int[] indeks(int[] a)
{
    int[] indeks = { 0, 1, 2 }; 

      if(a[1] < a[0]) 
      {
         int temp = indeks[0];
         indeks[0] = indeks[1];
         indeks[1] = temp;
      }
      if(a[2] < a[0]) 
      {
        int temp = indeks[0];
        indeks[0] = indeks[2];
        indeks[2] = temp;     
      }
      if(a[2] < a[1] ) 
      {
        int temp = indeks[1];
        indeks[1] = indeks[2];
        indeks[2] = temp;
      }


    return indeks;
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Suggestion 1) Add a language tag to your question.

Comment: In which language? Most will have way to get max value with index. So you can split array each time you have max element and its index.

Comment: First, there’s a saying, Don’t Repeat Yourself.  Your swap code repeats itself and is a prime candidate to be pulled out into a new function.  Second, remember that, when you swap elements of `indeks`, you do not swap the corresponding elements of `a`, so they get out of synch.

Comment: Yes, the idea is to not change "a" at all. Only to swap the indexes so that index[0] shows where the smallest number(of the three first numbers in a) is and so on.

Comment: @ssandoy Will you be doing this only for arrays of length 3?

Comment: @ssandoy Feel free for any queries.

Comment: Yes, only for arrays of length 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this has to be done within 3 comparisons then let me explain it using a game.

The game will be played between two numbers and the number which is greater wins the game and his score is incremented.

Initially all 3 numbers have score = 0.

Naturally there will be three games played.

**The largest number will be the one whose score is 2(greater than 2).The smallest number will be the one whose score is 0(greater than none) and the middle will be the one with score 1(greater than only 1).**

**Now the most important part is filling the index array which very easy but still i am going to explain it.The scores themselves speak in which position they should go by the operation**

```
score[i]%3;
```

and index will be filled as

```
index[score[i]%3]=i;
```

For example if score[1] is 2 then result will be 2 and index[2]=1.

So keeping this in mind,the function can be written as:

```
public static int[] indeks(int[] a)
{
 int []score=new int[3];
 int []index=new int[3];
 score[0]=0;score[1]=0;score[2]=0;
 //game b/w a[0] and a[1]
 if(a[0]>a[1])
  score[0]++;
 else score[1]++;
 //game b/w a[1] and a[2]
 if(a[1]>a[2])
  score[1]++;
 else score[2]++;
 //game b/w a[0] and a[2]
 if(a[0]>a[2])
  score[0]++;
 else score[2]++;
 //fill the index array
 index[score[0]%3]=0;
 index[score[1]%3]=1;
 index[score[2]%3]=2;     
}
```

Comment: This task is for an assignment, and in the assignment it says that it should be possible to do with only 3 comparisons, which is what I can't get to work....

Comment: @ssandoy Ok no problem,that is rather easy.